# Start Kodi when HDMI changed on Smart TV

Tags: boot, kodi

I am trying to set an script for autostarting kodi when the TV is on (not in standby mode) or when I change to the raspberry corresponding HDMI.

I found a script that should do this, but for what I've read it only works when the tv is switched off and not in standby mode.

```
#!/bin/bash

oldcmd=""
while :
do
    cmd=$(/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -n)
    if [[ "$cmd" == *"SAM-SAMSUNG"* && "$cmd" != "$oldcmd" ]]
    then
            echo starting xbmc
            $(sudo systemctl start mediacenter)
            oldcmd=$cmd
    elif [[ "$cmd" != "$oldcmd" ]] ; then


            echo stopping xbmc
            $(sudo systemctl stop mediacenter)
            oldcmd=$cmd
    fi


    echo $cmd
    sleep 10
done
```

Is there any way to change the script to only start kodi when the tv is not in standby or I select the corresponding HDMI output from the TV?

**Update**: I've made a change in the script to make it ping the tv (as pointed by Gotschi). This is the script if anyone wants it.

```
#!/bin/bash

status="off"
while :
do
        count=$( ping -c 1 $yourip | grep '64 bytes' | wc -l )

        if [[ $count -eq 0 && $status == "on" ]] ; then

                echo stoping xbmc
                $(sudo systemctl stop mediacenter)
                status="off"
        elif [[ $status == "off" ]] ; then


                echo starting xbmc
                $(sudo systemctl start mediacenter)
                status="on"
        fi


        echo $status
        sleep 10
done
```

Comment: well, I tried several methods utilising the HDMI port - until I realised my Smart Tv has a Ethernet port. Just plug in the cable, give it a static IP and ping for the TV in your script / check some port depending on your device.
Not an answer to your question, but a alternative solution...

Comment: you can check certain ports / upnp services or even make a arp lookup. my sony also took about 10 minutes to not respond when turned off, I didn't care...

Comment: Yes, I have made some changed and it works great! Thanks! I will add the new script to my question just in case someone needs it

Comment: Nice! I just remember fiddling around with the tvservice (hdmi-) port for a long time, but with no result...

Answer (score 1):

I come to a very similiar solution (pinging the TV static ip), and I integrated it into systemd;

this is the bash script in `/home/osmc/checkHdmi.sh` to be launched by the service:

```
#!/bin/bash

ping -c 1 -W 1 192.168.1.7 > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

    systemctl -q status mediacenter > /dev/null

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            sudo systemctl start mediacenter
    fi

else

    systemctl -q status mediacenter > /dev/null

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            sudo systemctl stop mediacenter
    fi

fi

exit 0
```

This is the service file in `/etc/systemd/system/checkHdmi.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Check if TV is on

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/osmc/checkHdmi.sh
```

and this is the timer file in `/etc/systemd/system/checkHdmi.timer` which launches the service every minute:

```
[Unit]
Description=Check if TV is on

[Timer]
OnBootSec=60
OnUnitActiveSec=60
Unit=checkHdmi.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Remember to enable and start the timer with the following commands:

```
systemctl enable checkHdmi.timer

systemctl start checkHdmi.timer
```